# Sort one column ascending and another column descending

Tags: sort

And by strange, I probably mean that it's intended behavior, but I don't understand *why*, nor how to fix it.

The task is to sort based on column 5, and then column 4.

```
grep -w RockDoveHPG_Transcript_21  xaa.blast| sort  -gk5,5 -gk4,4
```

which gives me

```
RockDoveHPG_Transcript_21   XM_004941221.2  70.588  17  4.17e-86
RockDoveHPG_Transcript_21   XM_004941221.2  82.353  17  4.17e-86
RockDoveHPG_Transcript_21   XM_004941221.2  68.182  22  4.17e-86
RockDoveHPG_Transcript_21   XM_004941221.2  80.000  25  4.17e-86
RockDoveHPG_Transcript_21   XM_004941221.2  57.692  26  4.17e-86
RockDoveHPG_Transcript_21   XM_004941221.2  70.588  34  4.17e-86
RockDoveHPG_Transcript_21   XM_004941221.2  100.000 77  4.17e-86
RockDoveHPG_Transcript_21   XM_004941221.2  77.778  18  2.46e-80
RockDoveHPG_Transcript_21   XM_004941221.2  89.474  19  2.46e-80
RockDoveHPG_Transcript_21   XM_004941221.2  70.000  20  2.46e-80
RockDoveHPG_Transcript_21   XM_004941221.2  71.429  21  2.46e-80
RockDoveHPG_Transcript_21   XM_004941221.2  72.000  25  2.46e-80
RockDoveHPG_Transcript_21   XM_004941221.2  72.727  33  2.46e-80
RockDoveHPG_Transcript_21   XM_004941221.2  94.737  76  2.46e-80
...
RockDoveHPG_Transcript_21   XM_004941221.2  78.947  19  1.56e-43
RockDoveHPG_Transcript_21   XM_004941221.2  71.429  21  1.56e-43
RockDoveHPG_Transcript_21   XM_004941221.2  83.544  79  1.56e-43
```

Col 5 sorts just fine, but ideally I'd like Col 4 sorted highest to lowest. Right now it's low to high. Ah, that sounds like I need the `-r` flag..

```
grep -w RockDoveHPG_Transcript_21  xaa.blast| sort  -gk5,5 -r -gk4,4
```

Now Col 5 is sorted in the opposite direction, but Col 4 is good.

```
RockDoveHPG_Transcript_21   XM_004941221.2  83.544  79  1.56e-43
RockDoveHPG_Transcript_21   XM_004941221.2  71.429  21  1.56e-43
RockDoveHPG_Transcript_21   XM_004941221.2  78.947  19  1.56e-43
RockDoveHPG_Transcript_21   XM_004941221.2  68.750  16  1.56e-43
RockDoveHPG_Transcript_21   XM_004941221.2  86.667  15  1.56e-43
RockDoveHPG_Transcript_21   XM_004941221.2  85.526  76  6.22e-44
...
RockDoveHPG_Transcript_21   XM_004941221.2  100.000 77  4.17e-86
RockDoveHPG_Transcript_21   XM_004941221.2  70.588  34  4.17e-86
RockDoveHPG_Transcript_21   XM_004941221.2  57.692  26  4.17e-86
RockDoveHPG_Transcript_21   XM_004941221.2  80.000  25  4.17e-86
RockDoveHPG_Transcript_21   XM_004941221.2  68.182  22  4.17e-86
RockDoveHPG_Transcript_21   XM_004941221.2  82.353  17  4.17e-86
RockDoveHPG_Transcript_21   XM_004941221.2  70.588  17  4.17e-86
```

So basically it seems like the `-r` flag is not applied column-wise.. Reversing order of 1 sorted column reverses the order of the other..

What I'd like, is to have

```
RockDoveHPG_Transcript_21   XM_004941221.2  100.000 77  4.17e-86
```

returned at the top, which I think *should* be accomplished by sorting Col5 lowest to highest and then Col 4 highest to lowest.

Comment: I believe something like:   `sort -k5,5gr -k4,4n ` is much more clear...

Answer (score 9):

By adding `-r` the way you did, it is being treated as a *global option*. From `info sort`:

> A position in a sort field specified with ‘-k’ may have any of the
>   option letters ‘MbdfghinRrV’ appended to it, in which case no global
>   ordering options are inherited by that particular field.

Note the phrase *"appended to it"* i.e. to reverse only field 4, use `-gk4,4r`

Answer (score 5):

use

```
grep -w RockDoveHPG_Transcript_21  xaa.blast| sort  -gk5,5 -gk4,4r
```

Notice the `r` at the end.

Comment: That's weird.. but it works. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @MattMacManes Actually, that's not weird. For each key to sort, you can have options which are placed after the key definition (see `man` page). Also your `-g` option could be placed behind the key, so you could do a different kind of sorting on the other key. So in your case better write `sort -k5g -k4gr` (why this `5,5` stuff anyhow?)